# How to prove that $\small\begin {cases} V = U_1\oplus U_2 \\U_1 \subseteq U_3 \end{cases} \Rightarrow U_3 = U_1 \oplus (U_2\ \cap \ U_3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $U_1, U_2, U_3$ subspaces of linear space $V$
>
> Given:
>   $$\begin {cases} V = U_1\oplus U_2 \\U_1 \subseteq U_3 \end{cases}$$
>   Prove that $U_3  =  U_1 \oplus (U_2\ \cap \ U_3) $?

I tried this:

$U_1 \oplus (U_2\ \cap \ U_3) \iff \begin {cases} 
 U_1 + (U_2 \cap U_3)\\ U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3 = \{0\}\end {cases}$

The second condition is trivial: $U_1 \cap U_2 = \{0\} \rightarrow U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3= \{0\}$
But how can I prove the first condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first condition,

Let $v\in U_3$. Then $v\in V$ and $v= u_1+u_2$ where $u_1\in U_1$ and $u_2\in U_2$. Now, 
$$
v= u_1+u_2, \ \ \mathrm{is} \ \mathrm{equivalent} \  \mathrm{to}\ \ u_2= v-u_1.
$$

Since $u_1\in U_1\subseteq U_3$, we have both $v$ and $-u_1$ lying in $U_3$. 
Thus, $u_2 \in U_3$. Therefore, $u_2 \in U_2\cap U_3$.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what next..
You have $u_2 \in U_2\cap U_3$
Can i just say that $v = u_1 + u_2 \rightarrow v = U_1 + U_2\cap U_3 \rightarrow W = U_1 + U_2\cap U_3$

Comment: As you had in your post, this one is the first condition. As you proved the second condition, you obtain what you wanted.

Comment: really? can I just say $v = u_1 + u_2 \rightarrow v = U_1 + U_2\cap U_3 \rightarrow U_3 = U_1 + U_2\cap U_3$
is this transformation from single vector to spaces is right?

Comment: To be more detailed, what I proved is that any $v\in U_3$ can be expressed as a sum of an element in $U_1$ and an element in $U_2\cap U_3$. So this proves that $U_3\subseteq U_1+ U_2\cap U_3$. In fact, the other inclusion is trivial. So, we are done.

Comment: if so, is it possible to use this $u_2 \in U_3$ to say that $U_2 \subseteq U_3$
and if not, what is the different?

Comment: This does not mean that $U_2\subseteq U_3$. This $u_2\in U_3$ also satisfies $u_2\in U_2$. Thus, all we can say is $u_2\in U_2\cap U_3$.